# Trigger a function when window is only above 1030px - and on Re-size or load

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make this following function trigger only when screen size is only above 1030px? (on re-size and on load) I tried to implement this line of code to it:  `var windowWidth = $(window).width(); if(windowWidth <= 1030){}` but it didn't work.

```
    //Change Header On Scroll//
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 40) {
        $("#headerWrapper").addClass("headerDown");
        $("#logo1").hide();
        $("#logo2").show();
    } else {
        $("#headerWrapper").removeClass("headerDown");
        $("#logo2").hide();
        $("#logo1").show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
window.onresize = function(){
    w = window.innerWidth;
}

If (w >= 1030) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Or in this case, since you're using 1030, you may wan to use window.outerWidth;

Comment: You could use Jquery to listen for resize by .resize() to update the value of var w.

Comment: If you do a js fiddle, I'd have a much easier time sorting it out. Glad to help, though. It's just tough to read since it's all crammed into a comment, inline.

Comment: Sorry, and thank you for helping mate, here: http://jsfiddle.net/gXWdr/ I just added the code where you say //your code here

Comment: I'm on ipad currently, and js fiddle is being a betch. I'll try when I get to my PC shortly.

Comment: You had the if typed as If with a capital I which results with an error and prevented from working, I have changed it to a small i so it - but it is sitll not working

Answer (score 1):

If the conditional you used is `if(windowWidth <= 1030)` then it will only be true if the window is less than or equal to `1030`.

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if (windowWidth >= 1030){
        // do yo' thang
    }
}
```